# Compiling external library

Tags: c++, qt, macros, qt-creator

I am very novice when it comes to using external libraries. Here is my problem:

I want to use this library in my project: [stk](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/download.html)
I download the library and unpacks. Then I go in terminal (Linux) to unpack directory and type:

```
sudo ./configure
```

after that type:

```
sudo make
```

Then liblary should be ready to use.

I add library to my project in Qt Creator by Add library. I am pointing path to .a and headers file. Auto-generated .pro file include this lines:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Pulpit/stk-4.5.0/src/ -lstk

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../Pulpit/stk-4.5.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../Pulpit/stk-4.5.0/include

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../Pulpit/stk-4.5.0/src/stk.lib
else:unix|win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../Pulpit/stk-4.5.0/src/libstk.a
```

Ok, fine. Everything works so far. I write simple code from tutorial and I get this error:

```
'MUTEX' does not name a type
   MUTEX mutex_;
   ^
 'CONDITION' does not name a type
   CONDITION condition_;
   ^
```

I go to Mutex.h file and I find:
[image]

This piece of code is in the grey background that means the condition is not fulfilled.
I guess in code isn't defined **OS_LINUX** macro. When could be this macro generated? When I run sudo ./configure ? Additionally if I delede the condition and leave only:

```
 #include <pthread.h>
  typedef pthread_mutex_t MUTEX;
  typedef pthread_cond_t CONDITION;
```

Then there is no problem in this file but is in other file which include some macros.

The question is: How to generate macro or why are not generated?

Comment: After you did `sudo make` did you do a `sudo make install` so that all files and headers get deployed properly?

Comment: Not before. I do this now but this isn't solve problem. One more thing. Headers are in stk-4.5.0/include or stk-4.5.0/src/include?

Comment: I haven't used stk, however `sudo make install` will copy the right set of headers to a place where they can be found - usually somewhere under /usr/local/include . the libs will be installed somewhere under /usr/local/libs . This is based on years of linux package building in general, not specific to stk